# Finding MySQL errors from LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: sql, mysql, load-data-infile

I am running a LOAD DATA INFILE command in MySQL and one of the files is showing errors at the mysql prompt.

How do I check the warnings and errors?  Right now the only thing I have to go by is the fact that the prompt reports 65,535 warnings on import.

```
mysql> use dbname;
Database changed
mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/dump.txt'
    -> INTO TABLE table
    -> (id, title, name, accuracy);
Query OK, 897306 rows affected, 65535 warnings (16.09 sec)
Records: 897306  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0
```

How do I get mysql to show me what those warnings are? I looked in the error log but I couldn't find them. Running the "SHOW WARNINGS" command only returned 64 results which means that the remaining 65,000 warnings must be somewhere else.

```
2 |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'accuracy' at row 2038
3 |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'accuracy' at row 2038
4 |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'accuracy' at row 2038
6 |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'accuracy' at row 2038
7 |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------
--+
64 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

How do I find these errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be a blank entry in the data file, and the target table doesn't allow null values, or doesn't have a valid default value for the field in question.

I'd check that the table has a default for `accuracy` - and if it doesn't, set it to zero and see if that clears up the errors.

Or you could pre-process the file with 'awk' or similar and ensure there is a valid numeric value for the accuracy field in all rows.

Comment: this is the answer? I think question is how to find the log from mysql?

Comment: Yeah, this isn't the answer.

Answer (score 14):

The MySQL `SHOW WARNINGS` command only shows you a subset of the warnings. You can change the limit of warning shown by modifying the parameter max_error_count.

Comment: Thanks, more info here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-warnings.html

Answer (score 2):

Getting that many errors suggests that you have the wrong delimiter or extraneous quote marks that are making MySQL read the wrong columns from your input.

You can probably fix that by adding

```
[{FIELDS | COLUMNS}
    [TERMINATED BY 'string']
    [[OPTIONALLY] ENCLOSED BY 'char']
    [ESCAPED BY 'char']
]
[LINES
    [STARTING BY 'string']
    [TERMINATED BY 'string']
]
```

after the tablename and before the column list.

Something like:

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/dump.txt'
INTO TABLE table
fields terminated by ' ' optionally enclosed by '"'
(id, title, name, accuracy);

By default, if you don't specify this, MySQL expects the tab character to terminate fields.

Comment: Yes, I thought that was it two. However, all the data seems to be being inserted correctly. Also, the file uses tabs to separate values so the default is correct. The thing that gets me is that out of 800,000 rows perhaps all 64,000 warnings are rows with "Incorrect integer value". I just am not sure how to check this when I can only view so many on the cmd line.

Comment: Well, notice the you have exactly 2^16 warnings, which suggests that a counter got maxed out and you actually have more. I'll get the error applies to every row. Are you sure that you got 800,000 rows inserted? What value do you have for the 'accuracy' column?

Comment: Thanks, I amended my post with this data.